# How to pass data to view only if it is defined?

Tags: php, laravel

As you can see in my piece of code below, $similarImages is being passed to the view, however, it is possible that there are no other similar images which means I'll pass an undefined variable. This is why I need to pass `'similarImages' => $similarImages` only if $similarImages exists.

```
$tag = Tag::whereHas('images', function($q) use ($id) {
            return $q->where('image_id', $id);
        })->first();

        if (!empty($tag)) {
            $tagId = $tag->id;
        }

        $recentImages = Image::where('user_id', $authorId)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get();

        if (!empty($tagId)) {
            $similarImages = Image::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tagId) {
                return $q->where('tag_id', $tagId);
            })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get();
        }

        return view('specificImage', ['image' => $image, 'recentImages' => $recentImages, 'similarImages' => $similarImages, 'author' => $author, 'comments' => $comments]);
```

Comment: `['image' => $image, 'recentImages' => $recentImages, 'author' => $author, 'comments' => $comments] + (isset($similarImages) ? [ 'similarImages' => $similarImages ] : [])` is what I sometimes do

Comment: give an empty default value or change the return view.... code

Comment: Define it first as `$similarImages = null` near the top of the function.

Comment: Do you really want it to be undefined in the view?  Or null? Or an empty collection?   I rarely think it's a good idea to have it be undefined.

Comment: Hey Devon, this is why I'm asking how to pass it ONLY if it's defined. Aynber's idea works quite well though.

Comment: For the purpose of logical integrity, values that should only be used in certain criteria should be defined in a null state (but still defined), to insure that separation of concerns is retained. The view should not be aware of the inner workings of the controller/model, it should only know how to render what it is given. Null does not explicitly mean `null`, it means any value that the logic knows to interpret as no operation (eg `null`, `false`, empty array/object, etc). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern

Comment: This is an easy way to avoid the possibility of missing key errors in the future, as any assumption or direct reference to `similarImages` will not break logic, it will just do nothing.

Comment: posted a new answer, can you try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the null-coalescing operator to have a default value:

```
[ .. 'similarImages' => $similarImages ?? collect(), .. ]
```

This will use $similarImages if it is defined and not null otherwise it will assign an empty collection created by `collect()`.

I like the idea of it always being a collection, but that's just me.

Comment: What does collect() do in this case?

Comment: Creates an empty collection, so you can always rely on it being a collection in the view.

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with collection, I tried google-ing collect() to read some documentation but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Whenever you use `get()` with a query builder, you're returning a collection of models.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections

Comment: `collect()` is a Laravel specific function for converting an `array` to a `Collection` , which is a wrapper/helper class. See here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections

Answer (score 0):

$array is always pass to the view

and if isset $similarImages, just prepend the $similarImages into $array

if not isset $similarImages just return $array (in this case $similarImages won't exists in blade)

here also you can use array_add($array, 'similarImages', $similarImages)

```
$tag = Tag::whereHas('images', function($q) use ($id) {
            return $q->where('image_id', $id);
        })->first();

        if (!empty($tag)) {
            $tagId = $tag->id;
        }

        $recentImages = Image::where('user_id', $authorId)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get();

        if (!empty($tagId)) {
            $similarImages = Image::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tagId) {
                return $q->where('tag_id', $tagId);
            })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get();
        }

        $array = [
            'image' => $image,
            'recentImages' => $recentImages,
            'author' => $author,
            'comments' => $comments
            ];

        if (isset($similarImages))
        {
            $array = array_prepend($array, $similarImages, 'similarImages')
        }

        return view('specificImage', $array);
```

Comment: Try to provide an explanation; the solution provided by code-only answers may not be obvious to all users, so a short explanation on what you've changed will go a long way.